# DecorationRenderOptions - problem creating a blue line under the text

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add a blue line under the text in range, but I keep getting a blue box around the text or the entire text blue

```
const blueMarkToggleType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    isWholeLine: false, // apply the text decoration only to the marked characters
    textDecoration: "underline", // solid, dark blue line under the text
    color: "#0000FF", // solid, dark blue color for the text decoration
    overviewRulerLane: vscode.OverviewRulerLane.Center
  });
```

Comment: don't use hard coded colors, if I use a blue theme I can't see the decoration, in package.json contribute a custom color, so the user can customize the color

Answer (score 0):

`textDecoration` can take many more options than just `underline`, it can include the colors directly of the underline - so the following would create a blue underline without all the text being colored (the `color` option applies to all the text):

```js
const blueMarkToggleType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    isWholeLine: false, // apply the text decoration only to the marked characters
    textDecoration: "underline #ff0000", // solid, dark blue line under the text
    // color: "#0000FF", // solid, dark blue color for the text decoration
    overviewRulerLane: vscode.OverviewRulerLane.Center
});
```

To try to deal with how your chosen `textDecoration` color (which I don't believe is themeable) will appear in dark and light themes you can override the default `textDecoration` by adding `dark` and `light` options like this:

```js
const blueMarkToggleType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
    isWholeLine: false, // apply the text decoration only to the marked characters
    textDecoration: "underline #ff0000", // solid, dark blue line under the text
    overviewRulerLane: vscode.OverviewRulerLane.Center,

    light: {
        textDecoration: "underline #0f0"  // green in a light theme
    },
    dark: {
        textDecoration: "underline #00f"  // blue in a dark theme
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution yet?